# SSH connect to HOSTNAME port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: ssh, webserver, cpanel, hosting-services

Using the "SSH Shell Access" in my Cpanel I have added my public and private key in the import key section and I also have authorised them. But I am getting this "Connection timed out" error on port 22. I have WHM access. How can I solve this connection timeout issue ?

Comment: 1. check the logs, 2. Try to troubleshoot it, no luck, 3. come here  [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/289422/edit) your post and paste logs here for others to troubleshoot

Comment: Sorry I am really new into this. I tried to analyse the log. From Log section in cpanel I tried different logs. I tried raw log history too. But nothing related to ssh access log. I tried error logs too but that is empty.

Answer (score 1):

1) Try to ping the host for checking the connection.
2) Confirm if SSH is listening to 22 or is listening on other port 
3) telnet host 22 to check the ssh connectivity 
4) From client you can try o ssh -vvv user@host in order to try to debug the ssh connection

Comment: I tried telnet host 22 but I am getting -
"telnet: connect to address x.x.x.x: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host".
what should I do next ?

Comment: you have to check the logs of ssh connection.
SSH auth failures are logged here /var/log/auth.log

The following should give you only ssh related log lines

grep 'sshd' /var/log/auth.log

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem and I found a solution:

Try this command line in your terminal:

```
ssh -i my_key -p 21098 root@198.54.116.163
```

- my_key : my private key SSH
- 21098  : my port (you can use 22 or other port)
- root   : my user
- 198.54.116.163: my server